# MySQL Coercibility on collation of expressions: why both expressions are unicode, it's an error?

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

This is from the MySQL documentation on Collation of Expression.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collation-expressions.html

I understand there are rules to determine the coercibility score and then MySQL use the coercibility score to resolve ambiguities.

The rule states:
"If both sides have the same coercibility, then:
   If both sides are Unicode, or both sides are not Unicode, it is an error."

What does that mean? Why is that both expressions are unicode would be an error? And under what conditions that error would occur?

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: @RickJames this is a question regarding MySQL official documentation, there is no example given in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm not an expert in this.*

When you compare two strings, MySQL needs to make sure that the two strings uses the same collation/character set (so the same comparison rules can apply).

When the strings uses different character set/collations MySQL has rules to determines which one should be converted into the other. The general rule is that non-Unicode character sets are converted into Unicode character sets.

However, when both sides are Unicode, and **presumably of a different Unicode character set/collation**, such as `utf8_general_ci` vs `utf8_bin`, then you get an error because MySQL can't decide which one should be converted into the other ("which side should win" as they say in the doc)

In layman's terms, it means you cannot implicitely compare a string stored in a column using collation A (e.g. `utf8_general_ci`) with a string stored in a column using collation B (e.g. `utf8_bin`) of the same character set (Unicode, or other). You will an error like this one:

> ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,EXPLICIT) and (utf8_bin,EXPLICIT) for operation '='

(Note: the error message can contain `EXPLICIT` or `IMPLICIT` or `COERCIBLE`, depending of the query)

The moral of the story: avoid mixing different collations in the same schema.

Comment: Caution:  "unicode" is a bit vague.  It could refer to the `CHARACTER SET ucs2`.

Comment: What you presumed in the example given is incorrect, because the rule clearly stated: "If both sides have the same coercibility...". In fact, that's why I was baffled.

Comment: @Devy How is the example incorrect? I have taken an example where both sides have the same coercibility (which is "EXPLICIT", i.e. 0 in this case), and both sides are Unicode... Isn't that what your question is about?

Comment: @rlanvin perhaps I didn't quite understand the coercibility vs. collation. And they are not the same thing?

Comment: @Devy No they are not. *Character set* determines how the string is encoded (stored). *Collation* determines how the strings will be **compared** (especially when ordering, e.g. is `ä` before, after, or equal to `a`?). *Coercibility* determines the ability of a a string to be **converted** into another character set/collation.